# Help in proof: a connected graph is $k$ edge connected iff all blocks are

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing

Attempt: we know that the edge set of $G$ is the union of those of it's blocks (maximal connected subgraphs of $G$ not having a cut vertex), any two of them touching in at most one vertex.

If all blocks are $k$ edge connected then deleting  $k-1$ edges from $G$ means deleting at most $k-1$ edges from some block, so all blocks are still connected. In particular we can still find a path between arbitrary vertices $u,v$ in $G$: if they lie in the same block then this just follows form the above reasoning. If they lie in different blocks then we can find a path from $u$ to the vertex of the block it belongs, connecting it to another block. Then from this vertex we can find a path to the next block and so forth (since all blocks are still connected) until we reach the block $v$ is in, and finally in that block we can find a path to $v$.

For the other direction (by contradiction): suppose there is a block $B$ which is not $k$ edge connected. Delete $k-1$ edges from it, disconnecting the block $B$ into $B_1,...,B_l$ components. Suppose $G$ is still connected, then we can find paths (in $G$) between any two of these components. One of these paths (call it $P$) has at least one edge that is not in $B$, otherwise $B$ would be still connected. But then $P \cup B$ would form a connected subgraph of $G$ with no cut vertex (this follows from a quick verification) which contains $B$ but is different from $B$, contradicting the maximality of $B$.

Is this ok or am I missing something? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you think you might miss something?

Comment: @salomo I worked on this problem a couple of weeks ago and i didn't get it right the first time. So i think a second opinion might be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks fine to me; I don't think you're missing anything.